# Simplifying Poor jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

wondering if anyone could give me a hand in simplifying this bit of jQuery:

```
$('.fixed-booking').on('mouseenter', function () {
    var booking = $('.fixed-booking'),
        tabHeight = $('.fixed-booking .nav-tabs').outerHeight(),
        contentHeight = $('.fixed-booking .tab-content').outerHeight(),
        bothHeight = tabHeight + contentHeight
    ;
    booking.css({
        'transform': 'translate(0,-' + bothHeight + 'px)'
    });
});

$('.fixed-booking').on('mouseleave', function () {
    var booking = $('.fixed-booking'),
        tabHeight = $('.fixed-booking .nav-tabs').outerHeight(),
        contentHeight = $('.fixed-booking .tab-content').outerHeight(),
        bothHeight = tabHeight + contentHeight
    ;
    booking.css({
        'transform': 'translate(0,-' + tabHeight + 'px)'
    });
});

$('.fixed-booking .nav-tabs a').on('click', function () {
    var booking = $('.fixed-booking'),
        tabHeight = $('.fixed-booking .nav-tabs').outerHeight(),
        contentHeight = $('.fixed-booking .tab-content').outerHeight(),
        bothHeight = tabHeight + contentHeight
    ;
    booking.css({
        'transform': 'translate(0,-' + bothHeight + 'px)'
    });
});
```

Also, when clicking on one of the navbar tabs the position only changes if I click twice.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Extract the core logic to a function.

Comment: Turn each one of those into a generic function with variable placerholders where things are different (the selector, translate's + ___ + variable, etc. Since they all do the same basic thing. Then assign the variables up top and just pass them in as parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any difference between each handler besides the height they end up using. You can just make that into a function:

```
function setHeight(both) {
    var booking = $('.fixed-booking'),
        tabHeight = $('.fixed-booking .nav-tabs').outerHeight(),
        contentHeight = $('.fixed-booking .tab-content').outerHeight(),
        bothHeight = tabHeight + contentHeight
    ;
    newHeight = both ? bothHeight : tabHeight;
    booking.css({
        'transform': 'translate(0,-' + newHeight + 'px)'
    });
}

$('.fixed-booking').on('mouseenter', function() {setHeight(true)});
$('.fixed-booking').on('mouseleave', function() {setHeight(false)});
$('.fixed-booking .nav-tabs a').on('click', function() {setHeight(true)});
```

As Pango mentioned, you may want to further generalize the `setHeight` function to make the base selector (`.fixed-booking`) more easily configurable. This is a great case for [higher order functions](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html).

Comment: Cheers Jamie, I knew roughly want I wanted just wasn't sure how. Much appreciated!

Comment: I updated my answer because there is one small difference in the functions. One takes `tabHeight` where the rest take `bothHeight`. Is this intended?

Comment: If you really want terse, you could create a variable for '.fixed-booking' as well.

It looks like newHeight needs the var keyword.

Comment: ReeceVail I have updated the answer to allow you to toggle between using both or just tab height using a boolean. @Pango, I agree. I was originally going to use a higher order function to return the callback based on the height to use and the selector, but there's no need to overcomplicate when someone is learning. I will add your comment as an edit for completeness.

Comment: Hey Jamie, yeah that was intended thank you. Everything is great now except for some reason it is still requiring two click on the navbar tabs a to update the height, any ideas?

Comment: @ReeceVail it may be best to open that as a separate question and include the HTML and any additional code. Take some time investigating before asking again right away.

Comment: @JamieCounsell Yeah good shout, still new around here... Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

As per jQuery's documentation http://api.jquery.com/on/ , you should be able to use multiple events in same line like below:

```
$('.fixed-booking').on('mouseenter mouseleave click', function () {
var booking = $('.fixed-booking'),
    tabHeight = $('.fixed-booking .nav-tabs').outerHeight(),
    contentHeight = $('.fixed-booking .tab-content').outerHeight(),
    bothHeight = tabHeight + contentHeight
;
booking.css({
    'transform': 'translate(0,-' + bothHeight + 'px)'
});
```

});

If you go to the bottom of the jQuery documentation, it shows how to  "Attach multiple events—one on mouseenter and one on mouseleave to the same element"

Hope this helps.

Thank you!

Comment: Good idea to use multiple events, but there is actually a small difference in the callbacks and the selectors used.